# Java Web Starter AMI

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2009/01/setting-up-amazon-ami-with-java-and.html but can't find the [Java Web Starter AMI](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1993&categoryID=101) (ami-1c54b075) when searcing for AMI in the AWS console. Anyone now why this could be? It seems to be one of the most popular AMIs as well ([see infobox on the right side](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=171)), so seems strange I cant find it...

Comment: I had great problems with the Java Web Starter AMi when I was playing with EC2 for work. I found that using one of the standard Fedora Core 8 AMIs and then installing what I needed was far more economical. Good luck either way.

Answer (score 3):

See this [forum post](http://solutions.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=29019). Probably the AMI was updated and the id changed. Perhaps ami-45e7002c is the newer version.